# Establish connection between analog and GSM modem

Tags: analog, gsm, modem, at-commands

I want to know if I can call a GSM modem (a SIEMENS MC55) from a normal analog (PSTN) modem. If so, how do I have to configure the GSM and the analog device? I've read about the +FCLASS and +CSNS commands but the connection doesn't work - I'm getting a BUSY or NO CARRIER. Are there other requirements?

Comment: Do you get a RING on the GSM modem and are you answering it?

Comment: @pjc50 The GSM device is build into a metering device. I can see in the log a 'Attempt to dial in'. Can I configure a 'automatic answer'?

Comment: I would expect that to be possible, but obviously the software on the other end has to support it.

Comment: @pjc50 I can set initialization strings for the GSM device, is there a command to enable auto-answer?

Comment: Check your documentation, but "ATS0=1" is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extending the initialization string of the GSM modem with 'AT+CSNS=4' the device was able to connect with analog modems.